# Set char pointer to NULL after using in a function

Tags: c, pointers, null, malloc

**In C,** I have a function in which I am getting a string as a parameter and then after using it, I want to destroy it, because I have to call it in an infinite loop and getting **Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)** after 5 minutes.

**Here's my function:**

```
void renderText(char *text) {
    //use it here and then destroy it.
    *text = NULL; //not working!
    text = NULL; //also not!
    text[0] = '\0'; //also not!
}
```

**Passing argument as:**

```
renderText("Hello There!");
```

> I can use a `malloc()` function to create a string and then can pass to the above function, but I have to call it infinite times so that is there any way to NULL it in the function as pointers are called by reference.

Comment: No I don't want to use it back, only in `renderText()` and then destroy

Comment: @Robert you cannot `free` the string literal in the example.

Comment: @WeatherVane because text is not dynamically allocated, I'm right?

Comment: yes, cannot `free` something which is not dynamically allocated

Comment: Yes, it is better to leave the job to the caller, who knows what was passed to the function. Please see the final sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

`void renderText(char *text) { }`

`text` is of `char*` type and after using it,  to not to point `text` to any invalid memory location its always better to initialize with `NULL` which means it points to nothing. Hence this

`text = NULL;`

is correct only in this API as it doesn't reflect `NULL` assignment in calling function as `text` is locally created in this function.
This

`*text = NULL;`

is not valid as `*text` is of `char` type while `NULL` is equivalent to `(void*)0`.

This

`text[0] = '\0';`

Works fine if error handling is according to above statement. For e.g

`if(strlen(text) != 0) { /* something is there inside text */ }`

Comment: `text = NULL;` is **incorrect**. It only sets the local copy of what was passed.

Comment: I think a better version of `if(text[0] != '\0')` would be `if(strlen(text) != 0)` or just `if(strlen(text)) `

Comment: @weatherVane Yes true. Its fine only in that APi where `text ` is assigned to `NULL`. In that case I would suggest to use `memcpy()`. For e.g after assigning `text` to `NULL` do `memcpy(arStruct->myString, text, strlen(text)+1);` assuming `struct` as argument & char array is member of that struct.

Answer (score 7):

This line

```
text[0] = '\0';
```

will dereference the pointer `text` but you have already

```
text = NULL;
```

so this will probably cause a segfault. You can

```
free(text);
```

but it is probably better to let the caller be responsible for that. This makes the function more useful for an argument that was *not* dynamically allocated, or that the caller wants to use again.

However your specific usage is

```
renderText("Hello There!");
```

and the string literal cannot be altered: it is read-only. So your function  **must not** try to kill the argument passed.

Comment: I have just shown that I have done the three LOC but I did these one by one.